# How can I determine if the Windows Server I'm looking at is using a mutliprocessor capable HAL?

Tags: windows-server-2012, hal

I have a Windows Server 2012 VM that has only been assigned a single core; I'd like to know if the HAL for the machine is multi-core capable before requesting more cores be added to the VM.

Is there some WMIC command, regedit value, or some other indicator?

I know in previous versions of Windows, I could tell by looking at the "oroginal file name" property for %SystemRoot%\System32\hal.dll -> Windows Server 2012 only shows "hal.dll".

I've looked through the MACHINE registry hive, but can't find anything close to meaningful.  I've also Googled "site:microsoft.com windows server hal multiprocessor", but none of the results are helpful.

Comment: As far as I know 2012 and later have only SMP HAL, so it's not an issue. And even 2008 will switch between them automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On x64 machines (and Server 2012 is always x64,) there is only one HAL image, called Hal.dll. (And it is always SMP-capable.)

However, as an academic experiment, if you want to see what HAL you are running, you can use Windbg and issue the command `lm vm hal`. Of course, on Server 2012, it will always be Hal.dll.

On older, x86 versions of Windows, you might see different HALs here, such as `Halacpi.dll` or `Halmacpi.dll`.

Here is an example of using LiveKD (from Sysinternals) :

[image: livekd]